# XGBoost with GPU Support + Python3

Tags: python, xgboost

I am trying to install XGBoost with GPU support on Ubuntu 16.04 & Python 3.5.2. I have tried to follow the [XGBoost documentation](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-with-gpu-support) by implementing the following steps:

**Building the Ubuntu distribution**

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; make -j4
```

**Enabling GPU Support**

```
cd build
cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON
make -j
```

**Install Python Package**

```
cd python-package; sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Everything seems to work until the step where I attempt to build the Python Package and I get an error that appears to be python 2 compatibility issue. Specifically:

```
...
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/sparse_batch_page.h -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/simple_dmatrix.h -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/simple_dmatrix.cc -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/sparse_page_source.h -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.h -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/simple_csr_source.cc -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/simple_csr_source.h -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/sparse_page_source.cc -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.cc -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/sparse_page_writer.cc -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/sparse_page_raw_format.cc -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/data/data.cc -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src/data
copying build/lib/xgboost/src/cli_main.cc -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/src
copying build/lib/xgboost/callback.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/plotting.py to plotting.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/rabit/guide/broadcast.py to broadcast.cpython-35.pyc
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/rabit/guide/broadcast.py", line 18
    print '@node[%d] before-broadcast: s=\"%s\"' % (rank, str(s))
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/rabit/guide/basic.py to basic.cpython-35.pyc
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/rabit/guide/basic.py", line 20
    print '@node[%d] before-allreduce: a=%s' % (rank, str(a))
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/rabit/guide/lazy_allreduce.py to lazy_allreduce.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/rabit/test/local_recover.py to local_recover.cpython-35.pyc
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/xgboost/rabit/test/local_recover.py", line 16
    print '[%d] restart from version %d' % (rank, version)
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

...

creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying xgboost.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
creating 'dist/xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg
removing '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg
Extracting xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg to /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg/xgboost/rabit/guide/basic.py", line 20
    print '@node[%d] before-allreduce: a=%s' % (rank, str(a))
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg/xgboost/rabit/guide/broadcast.py", line 18
    print '@node[%d] before-broadcast: s=\"%s\"' % (rank, str(s))
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg/xgboost/rabit/test/local_recover.py", line 16
    print '[%d] restart from version %d' % (rank, version)
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I try to run the XGBoost speed benchmark tests, as described [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu/), I get the following error - which I assume is related to the above.

```
[14:03:24] include/dmlc/logging.h:235: [14:03:24] src/io/local_filesys.cc:61: LocalFileSystem.GetPathInfo dtest.dm Error:No such file or directory
Generating dataset: 1000000 rows * 50 columns
0.25/0.75 test/train split
Generate Time: 49.93979454040527 seconds
DMatrix Start
Exception ignored in: <bound method DMatrix.__del__ of <xgboost.core.DMatrix object at 0x7f5448daa390>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 324, in __del__
    _check_call(_LIB.XGDMatrixFree(self.handle))
AttributeError: 'DMatrix' object has no attribute 'handle'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/benchmark/benchmark.py", line 16, in run_benchmark
    dtest = xgb.DMatrix('dtest.dm')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 262, in __init__
    ctypes.byref(self.handle)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 127, in _check_call
    raise XGBoostError(_LIB.XGBGetLastError())
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: b'[14:03:24] src/io/local_filesys.cc:61: LocalFileSystem.GetPathInfo dtest.dm Error:No such file or directory'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/benchmark/benchmark.py", line 65, in <module>
    run_benchmark(args)
  File "tests/benchmark/benchmark.py", line 39, in run_benchmark
    dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, y_test, nthread=-1)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nthread'
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Or can people see an issue with the install method above?

Answer (score 0):

> > print '[%d] restart from version %d' % (rank, version)

This is definitely python 2 syntax, you should use python 2 or try to find xgboost package for python 3